# scrapy is giving the error, no attribute 'OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE'

Tags: python, scrapy

When I use Scrapy to write a spider, I keep getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE'
```

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class ZhihuSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "zhihu"
    allowed_domains = ["www.zhihu.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.zhihu.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        print '\n\n\n 1 \n\n\n'
        return [scrapy.Request('http://www.zhihu.com/#signin')]

    def parse(self, response):
        print '\n\n\n2\n\n\n'
        print response
```

Comment: what version of Scrapy and pip are you using?

Comment: pip:pip 7.0.3+xy.11    scrapy :1.3.2

Comment: I'm having trouble installing scrapy with pip 7.0.3, however I can install it at the latest version of pip, 9.0.1 and your code runs fine. You might want to try using the latest version of pip in an virtualenv and see if you still get the error

Comment: by your way, the error is none,but ,the new error comes,the error is "TypeError: to_bytes must receive a unicode, str or bytes object, got set
"